# Создание объекта без присвоения ссылки

Tags: java, сборщик-мусора

Есть класс, в конструкторе которого создается асинхронный слушающий сокет. Вся работа с сокетом реализована в этом классе и внешняя ссылка на этот класс не нужна.

Вопрос, на сколько корректен такой способ создания объекта класса

```
new Server();
```

т.е. без присвоения созданного экземпляра переменной. Не прибьет ли такой объект сборщик мусора?

Comment: Где вызывается `new Server()`? В `main()`?

Comment: Насколько это вообще хорошо/красиво, выполнять/запускать кучу бизнес-логики в конструкторе, при создании инстанса объекта? Не лучше ли провести по минимуму инициализацию через конструктор, и вручную запустить всю логику через отдельный метод, поместив инстанс объекта в поле/переменную?

Comment: вероятно "не прибьет", но сказать наверняка можно будет только взглянув на код

Comment: @PeterSamokhin вынести логику в отдельный метод - да, но зачем в данном случае поле/переменная? `new Server().start();` да и всё.

Comment: @Ramiz а по взгляду на какой код вы хотите сказать наверняка?

Comment: @Regent на Server (и все его зависимости)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

При вызове каждого метода создаётся стековый кадр. Операция `new` поместит ссылку на объект в стековый кадр того метода, который её вызвал. Даже без присвоения этой ссылки переменной, она будет сохраняться в стеке до тех пор, пока метод не закончится и стековый кадр не будет уничтожен. А сборщик мусора не трогает те объекты, на которые есть ссылки в стеке.

Comment: Метод? Или текущий блок `{...}`?

Comment: Метод. Блоки могут влиять на границы видимости переменных, но эта конструкция языка и существует она только до момента компиляции. В байткоде информации о блоках уже не будет и виртуальная машина ничего о них не узнает.