# Безымянный обьект (не класс а именно обьект) и сборщик мусора

Tags: java, объекты, сборщик-мусора

Вопрос написан в комменте кода

```
public class ClassC {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ClassD(); //когда такой обьект будет удален сборщиком мусора? 
                      //интересно знать все возможные варианты.
    }
}
```

вопрос возник в первую очередь на основе утверждения, что обьекты не имеющие ссылки на себя уничтожаются сборщиком мусора. Получается что безымянный обьект должен уничтожаться сразу же после своего создания. Но думаю это неправильное понимание, поэтому решил задать тут в виде вопроса.

Comment: то, что у объекта нет явной ссылки в коде, не значит, что ее нет совсем. компилятор создаст для такого объекта неявную ссылку, которая имеет те же свойства, что и явная. Подробнее про это почитайте про анонимные классы. В вашем случае, пока не будет уничтожен класс С, с классом Д ничего не случится

Comment: а как можно получить эту неявную ссылку? Ну посмотреть, использовать,...

Comment: из клиентского кода  никак, если вам нужна явная ссылка на объект, ее надо сохранить в переменную соответствующего типа. анонимные классы используются, когда объект нужен одноразово и дальнейшее взаимодействие с ним не планируется

Comment: Благодарю за четкие ответы. Мне нравится как вы формулируете ваши мысли.

Comment: [аналогичный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/813629/177345). так же надо уточнить, что в вашем случае мы имеем не полноценный анонимный класс, так как его отличает переопределение метода/реализация интерфейса, но в части ссылки на такой класс все происходит так же, как с анонимным

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут все зависит от содержимого класса `ClassD`

```java
public class ClassD {
    private static Vector<ClassD> instances = new Vector<>();

    ClassD() {
        instances.add(this);
    }
}
```

Такой объект удален не будет, потому, что ссылка на него останется в `instances`

Даже если ссылок не останется вовсе, это не значит, что объект будет удален сиюсекундно: сборщик мусора запускается тогда, когда система посчитает это необходимым.

Не беспокойтесь о том, что объект, который используется в какой-то мере, будет неожиданно удален сборщиком мусора: если объект хоть как-то кем-то используется, у этого кого-то на него обязательно останутся ссылки, и, следовательно, удален он не будет.

Comment: А если в классе ClassD  нет ничего такого особенного, с помощью которого будет ссылка на создаваемый обьект и изначально обьект создан без ссылки на себя?

Comment: @RubenKubalyan удаление последней ссылки на объект - равносильно его смерти. Если в `ClassD` (и его базовых классах) нет явного или неявного сохранения ссылки, и вызывающая сторона ссылку не сохраняет - с этим объектом никогда больше ничего не произойдет, и сборщику мусора, когда представится такая возможность, остается только его удалить из памяти как мертвый груз.

Comment: класс Д - анонимный класс и на него создаётся неявная ссылка зависящая от класса С.

Comment: @pavlofff Речь не об анонимном классе, а об экземпляре конкретного класса "без имени" (не присвоен переменной).

Comment: да, это не полноценный анонимный класс, так как не переопределяются его методы / не реализуются интерфейсы, но в части ссылки с ним происходит то же, что и с анонимным классом.

Comment: основная мысль тут в том, что для любого создаваемого объекта создается и ссылка на него, которая закрепляется за вызывающим классом или методом. присвоение такой ссылки переменной - это только способ доступа к объекту, то есть зависимость здесь обратная - не ссылка зависит от переменной ее хранящей, а переменной присваивается ссылка, если есть необходимость сохранить ее для дальнейшей работы. Из вашего ответа можно подумать, что у такого объекта вообще **нет ссылки**, что в корне **не верно**. ее нет только для клиентского кода, но не для комилятора

Comment: @pavlofff Не знаю, что в моем ответе вас натолкнуло на мысль, что ссылки на объект не существует вовсе, но это явно не то, что я имел в виду.